# Business with dbcontext and static class

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static

Many speak of using dependency injection. I do not use repository. The entity framework is uow/repository. What is wrong with using static class like the one below? My context is a new instance per request.

```
public class TenantManager
  {
    public static IEnumerable<Tenant> GetAll(AppDbContext context)
    {
      return context.Tenants;
    }
    public static Tenant GetById(int id, AppDbContext context)
    {
      return context.Tenants.Find(id);
    }
    public static Tenant Create(Tenant entity, AppDbContext context)
    {
      var tenant = context.Tenants.Add(entity);

      context.SaveChanges();
      return tenant;
    }
    public static void Update(Tenant entity, AppDbContext context)
    {
      context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
    public static void Delete(int id, AppDbContext context)
    {
      var tenant = context.Tenants.Find(id);
      context.Tenants.Remove(tenant);
      context.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 22):

> *What is wrong with using static class like the one below?*

For one thing, your class isn't `static`, which means your client code *can* create an instance of it... which would make no sense at all.

Before the advent of `static` classes, you would prevent instantiation by sealing the class and providing a non-public default/parameterless constructor, like this:

```
public sealed class TenantManager
{
    private TenantManager() { }
```

Making the class `static` pretty much does that for you, and prevents anyone from inheriting the class and/or calling its constructor.

In Object-Oriented Programming, a class defines the "blueprint" for an object - its *type*. By making a class `static`, you're denying it the ability to create objects; you're writing *procedural code*, like [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) macro-recorder code in a *module* - you're giving anyone anywhere the ability to run this code, because the code lives in a global state, a static context, a *type*, as opposed to an *object*. This simply isn't OOP code.

It wouldn't be that bad, if all there ever was to your application was a `Tenant` entity. I don't know about the rest of your app, but say you have new requirements and now you have to add a `Landlord` entity, with the corresponding `LandlordManager` class.

So you go and implement another `static` class:

```
public static class LandlordManager
{
    public static IEnumerable<Landlord> GetAll(AppDbContext context)
    {
        return context.Landlords;
    }

    public static Landlord GetById(int id, AppDbContext context)
    {
        return context.Landlords.Find(id);
    }

    public static Landlord Create(Landlord entity, AppDbContext context)
    {
        var landlord = context.Landlords.Add(entity);

        context.SaveChanges();
        return landlord;
    }

    public static void Update(Landlord entity, AppDbContext context)
    {
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void Delete(int id, AppDbContext context)
    {
        var landlord = context.Landlords.Find(id);
        context.Landlords.Remove(landlord);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Notice anything? Yes, I fixed the vertical whitespace and the shy indentation. Anything else? Isn't it striking how similar the two classes are? The two types desperately *want* to share an interface, but the classes being `static`, they can't.

```
public interface IEntityManager<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(AppDbContext context);
    TEntity GetById(int id, AppDbContext context);
    TEntity Create(TEntity entity, AppDbContext context);
    void Update(TEntity entity, AppDbContext context);
    void Delete(TEntity entity, AppDbContext context);
}
```

The fact that every single member of the interface takes an `AppDbContext` parameter, is a very strong indicator that the parameter belongs at *instance level*. This simplifies the interface to this:

```
public interface IEntityManager<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    TEntity Create(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

This is really starting to look like something familiar - in fact only the name is different:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
    TEntity GetById(int id);
    TEntity Create(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
}
```

> *I do not use repository. The entity framework is uow/repository.*

The thing is, you *are* using a repository. You just gave it a different name. I can call an apple an orange all I want, it's still an apple. Yes, the EF `DbContext` is a powerful unit-of-work. Yes, an EF `DbSet<T>` is a nice repository. Yet you still feel the need to tuck it into its own type - and that's a good thing!

The difference between your `TenantManager` and the above `IRepository<TEntity>` interface, is that `TenantManager` is tightly coupled with `AppDbContext`, while it's an *implementation detail* as far as `IRepository<TEntity>` is concerned - the consuming/client code doesn't need to even know about `AppDbContext`. In your code, `AppDbContext` is a dependency: not only your code needs to be tightly coupled with a `TenantManager`, it's also coupled with `AppDbContext`. "Manager" is a smell all by itself - you don't have a "Manager", you have a repository... whether you like it or not!

Good design doesn't spread its dependencies to the client/consuming code; good design is cohesive, and has *low coupling*. That's why SOLID OOP guidelines tell us to *depend on abstractions, not concrete types*. With client code that only needs to know about an `IRepository<Tenant>`, the only concrete type it's working with is `Tenant`. With your code, it needs to know about `Tenant`, `TenantManager`, and `AppDbContext`. That's not exactly what *low coupling* is about!

> *Many speak of using dependency injection.*

There's a reason for this. Loosely coupled code is much easier to write tests for. And the DI principle (all of SOLID actually) completely steer your code/design in that direction.

Say you have a controller - with your code it could look like this:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Tenant(int id)
    {
        using (var context = new AppDbContext(connectionString))
        {
            var tenant = TenantManager.GetById(id, context);
            return View(tenant);
        }
    }
}
```

With proper DI it could look like this:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IRepository<Tenant> _repository;

    public SomeController(IRepository<Tenant> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Tenant(int id)
    {
        var tenant = _repository.GetById(id);
        return View(tenant);
    }
}
```

Both do exactly the same thing. Yet, only one of these two snippets can be unit tested.