# Tracking Containers in a Train Station

Tags: java, json, javafx, rest, data-visualization

This is a time line for control over the events of some containers in a train station.

It gets all the data to build the time line by getting a JSON from a database via REST service. The app resets every minute to refresh the results and every dot representing a container has some info in a tooltip activated by hovering the mouse.

The app needs 3 external libraries:

- commons-io-2.4.jar
- guava-18.0.jar
- json-simple-1.1.1.jar

There is also a webstart test version online, please use Firefox if you want to try it out: http://www.abaxomol.com/dist/ContenedoresChart.html

**ContenedoresChart.java**

```
public class ContenedoresChart extends Application {
    DrawDots drawDots = new DrawDots();
    static DotsArrays dotsArrays = new DotsArrays();
    final static NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final static CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();       
    final static LineChart<Number, String> sc = new
                 LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
    static String fullJSON = "";
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
                  NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
          CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();    
          LineChart<Number, String> sc = new
              LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

          Get_JSON_String.getJSONString();
          primaryStage.setTitle("Ferroservicios");
          DateFormatter.dateFormatter(xAxis);
          xAxis.setLabel("Fecha");                
          yAxis.setLabel("Contenedores");
          sc.setTitle("Eventos de Contenedores");
          SeparateContenedores.loadDots(sc);
          //sc.setLegendVisible(false);
          SetTooltip.setTooltip();
          SetTooltip.setSeriesStyle(sc);

          LegendItems.setItems(sc);
          LegendItems.setTransparent();
          Legend legend = (Legend)sc.lookup(".chart-legend");
          legend.getItems().removeIf(item->item.getText().equals("hide"));

          Scene scene  = new Scene(sc, 1200, 1000); 
          //primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
          primaryStage.setScene(scene);
          primaryStage.show();
          LegendItems.setLegendStyle(sc);
          SetRefreshRate.setRefreshRate(primaryStage, 60);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
    }
}
```

**DateFormatter.java**

```
public class DateFormatter {
    static String date1 = "";
    static String date2 = "";
    static String date3 = "";
    static String date4 = "";
    static String date5 = "";
    static String date6 = "";
    static String date7 = "";


    public static void dateFormatter(NumberAxis xAxis){
        loadDates();
        xAxis.setLowerBound(0.0);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(7.4);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setTickUnit(1);
        xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number n) {
                if (n.equals(1.00)) return date1;
                if (n.equals(2.00)) return date2;
                if (n.equals(3.00)) return date3;
                if (n.equals(4.00)) return date4;
                if (n.equals(5.00)) return date5;
                if (n.equals(6.00)) return date6;
                if (n.equals(7.00)) return date7;
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });    
    }

    public static void loadDates(){
        try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        String urlJSON = ContenedoresChart.fullJSON;
        JSONObject JSON_obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(urlJSON);
        //set the value of the dates
        JSONObject namesArray = (JSONObject) JSON_obj.get("dates");
        date1 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date1"));
        date2 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date2"));
        date3 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date3"));
        date4 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date4"));
        date5 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date5"));
        date6 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date6"));
        date7 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date7"));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
        //ErrorHandling.showException();
        }
    }
}
```

**DotsArray.java**

```
public class DotsArrays {
    static JSON_Reader reader = new JSON_Reader();
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<XYChart.Data>> arrayOfContainers = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void loadDots(){
    SeparateContenedores.loadNames();
    arrayOfContainers.clear();
    for(int x=0; x<SeparateContenedores.arrayOfNames.size(); x++){
        ArrayList<XYChart.Data> contenedor = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayOfContainers.add(contenedor);
        reader.setDots(contenedor,SeparateContenedores.arrayOfNames.get(x));
     }
    } 
}
```

**DrawDots.java**

```
public class DrawDots {

  public static ListMultimap<String, String> dataMap =       ArrayListMultimap.create();

    public static void drawJSONdots(ArrayList<XYChart.Data> dotArray, XYChart.Series series){
        for(int x = 0; x<dotArray.size();x++){
          series.getData().add(dotArray.get(x));
        }
    }

public static void hackTooltipStartTiming(Tooltip tooltip) {

    try {
        Field fieldBehavior = tooltip.getClass().getDeclaredField("BEHAVIOR");
        fieldBehavior.setAccessible(true);
        Object objBehavior = fieldBehavior.get(tooltip);

        Field fieldTimer = objBehavior.getClass().getDeclaredField("activationTimer");
        fieldTimer.setAccessible(true);
        Timeline objTimer = (Timeline) fieldTimer.get(objBehavior);

        objTimer.getKeyFrames().clear();
        objTimer.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(new Duration(100)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}   

}
```

**ErrorHandling.java**

```
    public class ErrorHandling {

     public static Alert showException(){
      Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
      alert.setTitle("Error JSON");
      alert.setHeaderText("Error en el archivo JSON");
      alert.setContentText("No se pudo obtener el archivo JSON");

      Exception ex = new FileNotFoundException("Could not retrieve JSON text");

      // Create expandable Exception.
      StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
      ex.printStackTrace(pw);
      String exceptionText = sw.toString();

      Label label = new Label("The exception stacktrace was:");

      TextArea textArea = new TextArea(exceptionText);
      textArea.setEditable(false);
      textArea.setWrapText(true); 

      textArea.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
      textArea.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
      GridPane.setVgrow(textArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
      GridPane.setHgrow(textArea, Priority.ALWAYS);

      GridPane expContent = new GridPane();
      expContent.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
      expContent.add(label, 0, 0);
      expContent.add(textArea, 0, 1);

      // Set expandable Exception into the dialog pane.
      alert.getDialogPane().setExpandableContent(expContent);

      alert.showAndWait();

      return alert;
        }
    }
```

**Get_JSON_String.java**

```
public class Get_JSON_String {

  public static void getJSONString(){
      try{
      ContenedoresChart.fullJSON = IOUtils.toString(new URL("http://mic.abaxomol.com:8080/apex/mic_ferro.JSON_CONTAINERS_TIMELINE_PARM?p_dias_atras=3&p_id_consignatario=1088"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       ErrorHandling.showException();
        }
  }

}
```

**JSON_Reader.java**

```
    public class JSON_Reader {
        static String nombre;
        static String fecha;
        static String hora;

        public static void setDots(ArrayList<XYChart.Data> dotsArrayList, String name){
            Integer numOfEvents;
            try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            // get the data
            String urlJSON = ContenedoresChart.fullJSON;
            JSONObject JSON_obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(urlJSON);
            JSONArray dayArray = (JSONArray) JSON_obj.get(name);
            // get the object of the loop
            JSONObject numOfEventsJSON = (JSONObject) dayArray.get(0);

            numOfEvents = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numOfEventsJSON.get("numEventos")));

            if (numOfEvents.equals(1)) {
              JSONObject contenedorArray = (JSONObject) dayArray.get(1); 
              Double fecha = Double.parseDouble((String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("fecha"))));
                String hora = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("hora"));
                String nombre = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("nombre"));
                String id = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("ID"));
                String confirmado = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("confirmado"));
                String tipo_evento = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("tipo_evento"));
                String vacio_lleno = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("vacio_lleno"));
                String extraValue = ("Nombre: "+nombre+"\n"
                        +"ID: "+id+"\n"
                        +"Fecha y Hora: "+hora+"\n"
                        +"Confirmado: "+confirmado+"\n"
                        +"Tipo de Evento: "+tipo_evento+"\n"
                        +"Vacio/Lleno: "+vacio_lleno);
              XYChart.Data contenedor = new XYChart.Data(fecha, nombre);
              dotsArrayList.add(contenedor);
              LegendItems.nombre = nombre;
              contenedor.setExtraValue(extraValue);
            } else {
                for(int x = 1; x<=numOfEvents; x++){
                JSONObject contenedorArray = (JSONObject) dayArray.get(x);
                Double fecha = Double.parseDouble((String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("fecha"))));
                String hora = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("hora"));
                String nombre = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("nombre"));
                String id = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("ID"));
                String confirmado = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("confirmado"));
                String tipo_evento = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("tipo_evento"));
                String vacio_lleno = String.valueOf(contenedorArray.get("vacio_lleno"));
                String extraValue = ("Nombre: "+nombre+"\n"
                        +"ID: "+id+"\n"
                        +"Fecha y Hora: "+hora+"\n"
                        +"Confirmado: "+confirmado+"\n"
                        +"Tipo de Evento: "+tipo_evento+"\n"
                        +"Vacio/Lleno: "+vacio_lleno);
                XYChart.Data contenedor = new XYChart.Data(fecha, nombre);
                dotsArrayList.add(contenedor);
                LegendItems.nombre = nombre;
                contenedor.setExtraValue(extraValue);
                }
            }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("hubo un problema con el json");
            }
        }

        public static Integer getNumberOfContainers(){
            Integer numberOfContainers = 0;
            try {
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            // get the data
            String urlJSON = ContenedoresChart.fullJSON;
            JSONObject JSON_obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(urlJSON);
            numberOfContainers = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(JSON_obj.get("numberofcontainers")));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("hubo un problema con el json");
            }
        return numberOfContainers;
        }

    }
```

**LegendItems.java**

```
    public class LegendItems {
    static String nombre = "";
    static XYChart.Series vacio_series = new XYChart.Series();
    static XYChart.Series lleno_series = new XYChart.Series();

    public static void setItems(LineChart<Number, String> sc){

        vacio_series.setName("Contenedor Vacio");
        vacio_series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(-1, nombre));
        sc.getData().add(vacio_series);

        lleno_series.setName("Contenedor Lleno");
        lleno_series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(-1, nombre));
        sc.getData().add(lleno_series);
    }

    public static void setTransparent(){
        lleno_series.getNode().setVisible(false);
        vacio_series.getNode().setVisible(false);
    }

    public static void setLegendStyle(LineChart<Number, String> chart){
Set<Node> items = chart.lookupAll("Label.chart-legend-item");
    int i = 0;
    // these colors came from caspian.css .default-color0..4.chart-pie
    Color[] colors = {Color.web("#808080")};
    for (Node item : items) {
      Label label = (Label) item;
      final Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(13, 13, colors[0]);
      final Circle circle = new Circle(10, 10, 7);
      final Glow niceEffect = new Glow();
      niceEffect.setInput(new Reflection());
      circle.setEffect(niceEffect);
      circle.setFill(colors[0]);
      rectangle.setEffect(niceEffect);
      if(i == 0){
        label.setGraphic(circle);  
      } else {label.setGraphic(rectangle);}
      i++;
    }
    }

}
```

**SeparateContenedores.java**

```
        public class SeparateContenedores {

      static ArrayList<String> arrayOfNames = new ArrayList<>();
      static int numberOfContainers = 0;

       public static void loadNames(){
       try {
            ContainerNames.loadNames();
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            //set the value of number of containers
            String urlJSON = ContenedoresChart.fullJSON;
            JSONObject JSON_obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(urlJSON);
            numberOfContainers = Integer.parseInt((String.valueOf(JSON_obj.get("numberofcontainers"))));

            //set the value of the names of containers
            JSONObject namesArray = (JSONObject) JSON_obj.get("namesofcontainers");
            arrayOfNames.clear();
            for(int x=0; x<namesArray.size(); x++){
              arrayOfNames.add(String.valueOf(namesArray.get(ContainerNames.names.get(x))));
            }

            } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("hubo un problema con el json");
            }
       }

       public static void loadDots(LineChart<Number, String> sc){
           loadNames();
           DotsArrays.loadDots();
           for(int x=0; x<DotsArrays.arrayOfContainers.size(); x++){
           XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
           series.setName("hide");
           DrawDots.drawJSONdots(DotsArrays.arrayOfContainers.get(x),series);
           sc.getData().add(series);
           }
       }

    }
```

**ContainerNames.java**

```
        public class ContainerNames {
        static ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        public static void loadNames(){
          names.clear();
          for(int x=1; x<=JSON_Reader.getNumberOfContainers(); x++){
              names.add("container"+x);
          }
        }
    }
```

**SetRefreshRate.java**

```
     public static void setRefreshRate(Stage primaryStage, int segundos){
  Task task = new Task<Void>() {
   @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
      final int finalI = i;
      Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
          CategoryAxis yAxis = new CategoryAxis();    
          LineChart<Number, String> sc = new
              LineChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);

          Get_JSON_String.getJSONString();
          primaryStage.setTitle("Ferroservicios");
          DateFormatter.dateFormatter(xAxis);
          xAxis.setLabel("Fecha");                
          yAxis.setLabel("Contenedores");
          sc.setTitle("Eventos de Contenedores");
          SeparateContenedores.loadDots(sc);
          //sc.setLegendVisible(false);
          SetTooltip.setTooltip();
          SetTooltip.setSeriesStyle(sc);

          LegendItems.setItems(sc);
          LegendItems.setTransparent();
          Legend legend = (Legend)sc.lookup(".chart-legend");
          legend.getItems().removeIf(item->item.getText().equals("hide"));

          Scene scene  = new Scene(sc, 800, 600); 
          if(finalI > 2){
          primaryStage.close();
          primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
          primaryStage.setScene(scene);
          primaryStage.show();
          LegendItems.setLegendStyle(sc);
          }
        }
      });
      i++;
      Thread.sleep(segundos*1000);
    }
  }
};
        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

**SetTooltip.java**

```
public class SetTooltip {
    public static void setTooltipProperties(ArrayList<XYChart.Data> array){
        for(int x = 0; x<array.size();x++){
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
             tooltip.setMaxWidth(300);
             tooltip.setWrapText(true);
             hackTooltipStartTiming(tooltip);
             tooltip.setText(array.get(x).getExtraValue().toString());
             Tooltip.install(array.get(x).getNode(), tooltip);
             boolean confirmado = array.get(x).getExtraValue().toString().contains("Confirmado: SI");
             boolean vacio_lleno = array.get(x).getExtraValue().toString().contains("Vacio/Lleno: LLENO");
             /*if(array.get(x).getExtraValue().toString().contains("Confirmado: SI")){
              array.get(x).getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #a9e200, #95c604;");   
             } 
             else {array.get(x).getNode().setStyle("-fx-background-color: #f1003c, #ae0000;\n" + "-fx-background-radius: 0;");}*/
             sb.append(createConfirmadoStyleString(confirmado));
             sb.append(createVacioLlenoStyleString(vacio_lleno));
             array.get(x).getNode().setStyle(sb.toString()); 
             //System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }

    public static String createConfirmadoStyleString(boolean confirmado){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if(confirmado){
          sb.append("-fx-background-color: #a9e200, #95c604;\n");
        } else {sb.append("-fx-background-color: #f1003c, #ae0000;\n");}

        String cssStyle = sb.toString();
        return cssStyle;
    }

    public static String createVacioLlenoStyleString(boolean vacio_lleno){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if(vacio_lleno){
          sb.append("-fx-background-radius: 0;\n -fx-padding: 5px;");
        }

        String cssStyle = sb.toString();
        return cssStyle;
    }

    public static void setTooltip(){
        for(int x=0; x<DotsArrays.arrayOfContainers.size(); x++){
           setTooltipProperties(DotsArrays.arrayOfContainers.get(x));
        }
    }

    public static void setSeriesStyle(LineChart<Number, String> sc){
        Set<Node> nodes = sc.lookupAll((".chart-series-line")); // series0 is the style class for first series
         for (Node n : nodes) {
         n.setStyle("-fx-stroke: black;\n" +
"    -fx-stroke-width: 1px;\n" +
"    -fx-effect: dropshadow( two-pass-box , rgba(0,0,0,0.3) , 8, 0.0 , 0 , 3 );");
         } 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public class DateFormatter {
    static String date1 = "";
    static String date2 = "";
    static String date3 = "";
    static String date4 = "";
    static String date5 = "";
    static String date6 = "";
    static String date7 = "";


    public static void dateFormatter(NumberAxis xAxis){
        loadDates();
        xAxis.setLowerBound(0.0);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(7.4);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setTickUnit(1);
        xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number n) {
                if (n.equals(1.00)) return date1;
                if (n.equals(2.00)) return date2;
                if (n.equals(3.00)) return date3;
                if (n.equals(4.00)) return date4;
                if (n.equals(5.00)) return date5;
                if (n.equals(6.00)) return date6;
                if (n.equals(7.00)) return date7;
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });    
    }

    public static void loadDates(){
        try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        String urlJSON = ContenedoresChart.fullJSON;
        JSONObject JSON_obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(urlJSON);
        //set the value of the dates
        JSONObject namesArray = (JSONObject) JSON_obj.get("dates");
        date1 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date1"));
        date2 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date2"));
        date3 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date3"));
        date4 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date4"));
        date5 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date5"));
        date6 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date6"));
        date7 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date7"));

        } catch (ParseException e) {
        //ErrorHandling.showException();
        }
    }
}
```

Looks good!

But then people say "Can we have a setting to pick how many labels we want to use?" and you're practically screwed. Especially if they want 1 for each day of the month. You'd have to add `date8` through `date31`. That's a lot of typing.

I'd use lists instead:

This

```
    static String date1 = "";
    static String date2 = "";
    static String date3 = "";
    static String date4 = "";
    static String date5 = "";
    static String date6 = "";
    static String date7 = "";
```

Becomes this

```
    static List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This

```
            @Override
            public String toString(Number n) {
                if (n.equals(1.00)) return date1;
                if (n.equals(2.00)) return date2;
                if (n.equals(3.00)) return date3;
                if (n.equals(4.00)) return date4;
                if (n.equals(5.00)) return date5;
                if (n.equals(6.00)) return date6;
                if (n.equals(7.00)) return date7;
                return "";
            }
```

Becomes this

```
            @Override
            public String toString(Number n) {
                int index = n.intValue()-1;
                if(0 <= index && index < dates.size()){
                    return dates.get(index);
                }
                return "";
            }
```

And this

```
        JSONObject namesArray = (JSONObject) JSON_obj.get("dates");
        date1 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date1"));
        date2 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date2"));
        date3 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date3"));
        date4 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date4"));
        date5 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date5"));
        date6 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date6"));
        date7 = String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date7"));
```

Becomes this.

```
        dates.clear();
        JSONObject namesArray = (JSONObject) JSON_obj.get("dates");
        for(int i = 1; namesArray.has("date" + i); i++){
            dates.add(String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date"+i)));
        }
```

You might need to check if you can use `has` or whether you need something like `hasString` or `hasKey` or `containsKey`.

The end result looks a lot better:

```
public class DateFormatter {
    static List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void dateFormatter(NumberAxis xAxis){
        loadDates();
        xAxis.setLowerBound(0.0);
        xAxis.setUpperBound(7.4);
        xAxis.setAutoRanging(false);
        xAxis.setTickUnit(1);
        xAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number n) {
                int index = n.intValue()-1;
                if(0 <= index && index < dates.size()){
                    return dates.get(index);
                }
                return "";
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });    
    }

    public static void loadDates(){
        try {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        String urlJSON = ContenedoresChart.fullJSON;
        JSONObject JSON_obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(urlJSON);
        //set the value of the dates
        dates.clear();
        JSONObject namesArray = (JSONObject) JSON_obj.get("dates");
        for(int i = 1; namesArray.has("date" + i); i++){
            dates.add(String.valueOf(namesArray.get("date"+i)));
        }

        } catch (ParseException e) {
        //ErrorHandling.showException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm really sorry, but after starting this review I have to tell you:

### Go back, read some more tutorials and try again

This code has so many issues, that I'm not able to point them out reasonably without saying something stupid and / or offensive, so I'll give you a few tips that should help you, if you rewrite this from scratch:

#### Avoid `static` Like The Plague

Let's get this straight: The **ideal** object-oriented project has **nothing**, I repeat **NOTHING** in `static` scope, that's data.
You should avoid static like the plague, unless you're implementing pure functions (methods without state or side-effects).

#### Encapsulation

A class should be jealous of it's data. **Never ever ever**<sup>1</sup> allow access to data that you can afford to hide. Use `private` wherever possible.

When you find yourself writing `ContenedoresChart.fullJSON = //...` stop and go back to the drawing board. Something in your design is fishy

#### Respect Conventions

This pertains to both naming conventions (`Get_JSON_String`, which shouldn't even exist) and indentation.
Your IDE should have automatic indentation. If it doesn't, get a new one. I can recommend any of Eclipse, IntelliJ and Netbeans.

#### Avoid Multithreading - For Now

I've edited it out, but you explicitly stated you're self-taught. Until you get the issues with `static` and object interactions under control, you shouldn't attempt to do multithreading. It's only going to be harder than necessary. And it's already difficult.

#### Learn To Use Your IDE

Start using `Refactoring`-features of your IDE like "Extract Method" and "Extract Local Variable" to reduce code-duplication. It's also a great way to make your code easier to understand.

#### Consistency Is King

Your names are a mess of Italian (?) and English. Choose one, stick to it. I'd recommend English, but you may just as well use Italian.
But **stick to it**

---

I think this concludes the first wave of advice I can give. I **strongly** urge you to come back here with either an overhauled (rewritten?) version of your code for a proper review. In addition to that I think you may be better off, writing some smaller things **without graphics** first.
In general these are more manageable.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course there's a few exceptions. These include things like allowing access to data-structure internals, the Builder Pattern, and other edge-cases that aren't relevant for you now.

Comment: When I learned java I learned the basics and from there I started to code without really learning any computer science related things, thats why all my methods start with public static I never really understood static or encapsulation so I always started my methods that way, and by not being in college I know nobody that can criticize my code so I always supposed it was not a big deal. My code is working how I want it to work but in a really general way what are the major flaws about the way I code? I agree that the language mix is a very bad thing but what else could go wrong with the code?

Comment: Also dont worry about being offensive, you are the first person that has helped me to get on the way to become a better programmer and I really appreciate that so a little bit of hard truth doesnt hurt.

Comment: I guess I didnt explained myself well in the last lines of the first comments, what im saying is: if the code works without worrying about static and encapsulation what would change if I took care of those things? I hope this doesnt sound too ignorant but I really dont understand those kind of internal things

Comment: @DiegoBarrena You sound like the situation I was in a year ago!  Keep posting here, and keep coding, and you will become much, ***much*** better very quickly.

Comment: @DiegoBarrena [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120835/business-with-dbcontext-and-static-class/120836#120836) is somewhat related - different language, but same concepts.